# Probability SAT MATH 2

Tags: probability

Two 6-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that the sum of the faces showing up is greater than 4?

A. 1/12

B.1/6

C.7/11

D.7/10

E.5/6

I got 5/6, but the Barron's solution says it is 1/6. I think the book is wrong?

Comment: You are correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the interior cells be the sum of the dice.
\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 &1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\\hline
2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\hline
3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\\hline
6&7&8&9&10&11&12
\end{array}

Notice that each cell is equally likely. Let's use the complement:
$$P(\text{sum }> 4) = 1-P(\text{sum } \leq 4) = 1 -\frac{6}{36} = \frac{5}{6}.$$

So I agree. The book is wrong.

Comment: Oh, hi again! No, just free time :)